# Truncate a string and add ellipsis at the end in Objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How to truncate a string in Objective-C and then add the ellipsis at the end?

Comment: Truncate it how, by number of characters or by a substring/delimiter.

Comment: number of characters, say a 100?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
NSString *origString = @"A very long string blah blah blah";
const int clipLength = 18;
if([origString length]>clipLength)
{
    origString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@...",[origString substringToIndex:clipLength]];
}
```

Comment: That does not take into account edge cases. You could see a space between the last word and ellipsis. (Although the question does not specify the behaviour)

Answer (score 11):

Use one of these `NSString` methods to truncate, probably the last:

```
– substringFromIndex:
– substringWithRange:
– substringToIndex:
```

and then use the `NSString` method

```
– stringByAppendingString:
```

to add `@"..."` or whatever ellopsis you like.

For example:

```
NSString *newString = [[string substringToIndex:12] stringByAppendingString:@"..."];
```

For your reading pleasure, I recommend the [`NSString` Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).

Comment: The issue with that solution is that it *always* appends the ellipses, when it only should when it performs a truncation.

Comment: You'll get an NSRangeException if toIndex > [string length].  Answer below checks this.

Answer (score 9):

In case you wish to truncate and add ellipsis to a string with the maximum being a specific width, here is an implementation that takes into account font and size:

```
+ (NSString *)stringByTruncatingString: (NSString *)string toWidth: (CGFloat)width withFont: (UIFont *)font
{
    #define ellipsis @"..."
    NSMutableString *truncatedString = [string mutableCopy];

    if ([string sizeWithAttributes: @{NSFontAttributeName: font}].width > width) {
        width -= [ellipsis sizeWithAttributes: @{NSFontAttributeName: font}].width;

        NSRange range = {truncatedString.length - 1, 1};

        while ([truncatedString sizeWithAttributes: @{NSFontAttributeName: font}].width > width) {
            [truncatedString deleteCharactersInRange:range];
            range.location--;
        }

        [truncatedString replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:ellipsis];
    }

    return truncatedString;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Don't need chuck of code for do this.. 
the easiest way to do this,

**for drawRect**

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect{
    NSString *theText = @"bla blah bla bhla bla bla";
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
    [style setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];
    [theText drawInRect:dirtyRect withAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:style, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName,nil]];
}
```

hear I use `dirtyRect` for String's Drawing area you can change it as you wish.

**for NSTextField**

```
NSTextField *_warningTF = [[NSTextField alloc]init];
[_warningTF setStringValue:@"sfdsf sdfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsf  1234566789123456789sfdsf dsf dsfdsf"];
[_warningTF.cell setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];
```

Answer (score 5):

I wrote simple category to truncate `NSString` **by words**:

```
@interface NSString (TFDString)

- (NSString *)truncateByWordWithLimit:(NSInteger)limit;


@end


@implementation NSString (TFDString)

- (NSString *)truncateByWordWithLimit:(NSInteger)limit {
    NSRange r = NSMakeRange(0, self.length);
    while (r.length > limit) {
        NSRange r0 = [self rangeOfString:@" " options:NSBackwardsSearch range:r];
        if (!r0.length) break;
        r = NSMakeRange(0, r0.location);
    }
    if (r.length == self.length) return self;
    return [[self substringWithRange:r] stringByAppendingString:@"..."];
}


@end
```

**Usage:**

```
NSString *xx = @"This string is too long, somebody just need to take and truncate it, but by word, please.";
xx = [xx truncateByWordWithLimit:50];
```

**Result:**

`This string is too long, somebody just need to...`

Hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

the drawWithRect:options:attributes:context method helps. you can try this:

[_text drawWithRect:_textRect options:**NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingTruncatesLastVisibleLine** attributes:attributes context:nil];